# comma separated string to array with key php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string

```
 $tailored_information="3, 5, 10, 13, 7, 6";
```

Now I have need to make an array like

```
$input_array = array("Id" => 3, "Id" => 5);
```

I am using this but not work cause i cant add key ID

```
explode(",", $tailored_information)
```

Comment: you could explode it. but you can't have that same key. keys are supposed to be unique

Comment: `$input_array = array("Id" => 3, "Id" => 5);` If you will have the array with same key, then all the values will be overwritted with the last value.

Comment: sometimes I don't understand people's purpose

Comment: dear i voted down you question because here people are trying to help you to understand that u can not make same key in an array but you are just voting down their answers...again and again so first try to  listen others and then voted their answers down...if you are here for help...

Answer (score 0):

An array has to have unique keys. Also, you will now have spaces in your values

What you could do is explode by `", "` and then take that array as your array straight away. If the key you want/need is always "Id" then it doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: All arrays need to have unique keys not only associative ones.

Comment: Yeah that's right. Put associative there because that was what Shre was aiming for

Answer (score 0):

As been told, you can't have array with the same key, because it is a hash table, which will override the "id" every time.
I suggest you to use simply

```
explode(", ", $id_array);
```

or

```
explode(", ", $another_arr['id']);
```

like this you will group the data by id...

If you wish to go into some more complicated - you could create your own data structure, which will be non-unique array -  where you will divide different values by key...
this way the print version will be whatever you want...

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$abc = "3, 5, 10, 13, 7, 6";
 $new_array = explode(',',$abc);
$new_id_array = array();
foreach($new_array as $key=>$val){;
    $new_id_array[$key]['id'] = $val;
}
print_r($new_id_array);
?>
```

you can not put same key in a array  key. so for that you have to create a nested array.and that will solve ur problem and now you can have same array key, but in different arrays.OR

```
$abc = "3, 5, 10, 13, 7, 6";
$new_array = explode(',',$abc);
foreach($new_array as $key=>$val){
    $new_id_array['id_'.$key] = $val;
}
```